# How to write or invoke -SQL cursor in spark/scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to write/invoke Cursor's in scala/spark?? I wanted to write or invoke( SQL cursor) the cursor from spark/scala code.

Below is the cursor (Written in SQL)  which i wanted to invoke it from the scala code.

```
declare
   cursor c1 is
       select DISTINCT earning_id from CN_TP_EARNINGS_ALL where rownum < 10;
   cursor c2(p_Assigned in number) is
       select SOURCE_EVENT_PERIOD_ID from  CN_TP_EARNINGS_ALL where 
       earning_id = p_Assigned;

begin
 for r1 in c1 loop
  dbms_output.put_line('------- start  --------');
  for r2 in c2(r1.earning_id) loop
     dbms_output.put_line(r2.SOURCE_EVENT_PERIOD_ID);
  end loop;
     dbms_output.put_line('------- end  -------');
 end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Stay with ORACLE. You can use iterators but seems the wrong use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the SELECT statement from the C1 cursor and then process the result set in a for loop in Scala and then use a prepared statement inside the loop to SELECT the C2 cursor values and loop again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).